# Question about definition of limit (specifically neighborhood definition)

Tags: limits

Using a neighborhood definition of limit: Let $f: D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, D\subset \overline{\mathbb{R}}$, and $a\in \overline{D \setminus \{a\} }$, $y\in \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is the limit of $f$ at $a$ if for every neighborhood $V$ of $y$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ or $a$ such that $f(U\cap D\setminus \{a\})\subset V$

Why is A in the closure of $D\setminus a$ **Note that our domain is a subset of the reals** ($D \subset \mathbb{R}$) Taking the closure obviously gives us $a$ back, and perhaps some other stuff?

Similarly (or another way of phrasing the question), the limit from the left/right is defined with $a\in \overline{D \cap (a, +\infty)}$. Why the need for the closure?

Comment: 1. $A=a$? 2. Not sure if I got your question right, but $a$ needs to be in $\overline{D}$ (which is the same as $\overline{D\setminus\{a\} }$ if $D$ is connected as you mentioned) since you want to be able to consider limits at the boundary. I.e. $f:(0,\infty )\to \mathbb{R},~x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$, you still want to evaluate the limit as $x\to 0$ or $x\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is needed to ensure that $a$ is a limit point for $D$, i.e. every neighborhood of $a$ contains some point of $D$. If $a$ is an isolated point of $D$ then $\overline{D \setminus \{a\} }$ is a closed set that does not contain $a$.

Comment: Just to note, since I just realized this (and I feel it adds to your answer), $a$ being a limit point and the definition using closure allows us to take the limit at points not defined by the function. For example, if $f(x) = 5 \text{, when }x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\neq 7$, the definition lets us take the limit at $x=7$ even though the function is not defined there.

Comment: Yes, of course: $a$ must be in the closure of $D$ (not necessarily in $D$) but must not be an isolated point.